# How can I scrape HTML button data?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am working on this project where the information I need is included in the button on the website. I am trying to scrape the number where the 97,800 is right now using python. This number changes every time the page refreshes. I have not tried anything yet because I am new to HTML with python. How would I go about this? Thank You.

Forgot to mention this but the number changes every second and I need to find a way where it pulls html from the url and not hardcoding the html ahead of time.

```
<div class="form-block">
    <button name="button" type="submit" data-disable-with="Please wait..." data- 
    confirm="Are you sure?" class="title-button">
        "Sell Now at "
        <img class="icons-stubs" src="randomphotourl.com">
        "  97,800 "
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to select the `<button>` tag and use the `.contents` property:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="form-block">
    <button name="button" type="submit" data-disable-with="Please wait..." data- 
    confirm="Are you sure?" class="title-button">
        "Sell Now at "
        <img class="icons-stubs" src="randomphotourl.com">
        "  97,800 "
    </button>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
value = soup.select_one("button").contents[-1].strip(' "\n')
print(value)
```

Prints:

```
97,800
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but the only issue is that the number changes every second. I need to find a solution where I don't hardcode the html ahead of time where it instead scrapes the webpage real time.

Comment: @MatthewPatience Most probably the price is loaded with JavaScript from external source. You can use `selenium` for example or use their API (if they have one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#input your url
url=" "
r1=requests.get(url)
c1=r1.content
soup1=BeautifulSoup(c1,"html.parser")



# Finding the location of button....Using find_all gives a list. You can 
# reference the exact button by filling the "NuM" below with the index 
# of the particular element
btn = soup1.find_all("button", {"class": "title-button"})[NuM].text
btn_text = btn.replace("Sell Now at ","")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This works in the sense that it finds a button with that class but the issue is there are many buttons with the same class name and this code finds the wrong one. Is there a way to specify which button to be found if they all have the same class name?

Comment: I have modified the answer. Instead of using "find", you can use "find_all", then reference the index of the element